# Firefox crashed and erased some of my settings

Tags: firefox

I have posted this on the FF forums as well in case somebody wonders. Just thought I'd get a better response here.

Just recently Firefox crashed and as usual I started it up again to restore my session, about 15 tabs. But I was met with a blank page and a message that Firefox couldn't restore the latest session. Then I was going to browse my older sessions (I usually have like ten of the latest sessions stored) and they were gone. In fact, it seemed like Firefox had done some kind of partial "factory reset".

The following is still stored:

- Stored logins and passwords
- My bookmarks
- My browser history
- SOME of my settings (not all, the starting page for example was NOT as I used to have it)

The following is completely gone:

- My session history. The .js AND .bak files in the
  sessionstore-backups folder have been overwritten so they are blank
  as well. Copying them to the main profile fodler and renaming them
  sessionstore.js does NOT work.
- My addons. Every single one of them is gone and it's as if I've never had them installed.

Has any one ever had this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've run into some Firefox profile issues. If you do `firefox -p` you'll get the profile dialog, or you can do some manual trickery with the folders.

It's been years since I last had this issue so I'm sorry to say I can't give you more advice. [This Mozilla help page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/recovering-important-data-from-an-old-profile) might be of use.